# Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных nvarchar к int

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь выполнить хранимую процедуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие параметры мне указать, чтобы все заработало?

Comment: У вас параметр strSex должен быть целым числом, а вы в него Male передаёте

Comment: И кстати, поменяйте типы данных на nvarchar везде, иначе будут приключения с русскими буквами

Comment: а что такое `Male` вообще тут? ни строка ни переменная.